# How to get top values from the list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have list of student with the column of name and their total marks and i want to know who are top 4 student on basis of marks which function i nee to use.

data like this:-

```
| Name | Total No. |
|------|-----------|
| m    | 450       |
| b    | 433       |
| c    | 456       |
| a    | 480       |
| e    | 412       |
```

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The data example you've posted is kind of confusing

Comment: Instead of a worksheetfunction, create a pivot table, filter on top 4.

Comment: You don't even need PivotTable, just select Top 10 in the table filter and change it to 4

Comment: Maybe use [Rank](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rank-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723).  [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Rank.aspx) has a good explanation on how to return the names based on the rank.  Saying that, the pivot table or sort option is probably the easiest.

Comment: @basic, that's even more basic =)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are aware of the `MAX` and `MIN` worksheet functions, to find the biggest and the smallest value in a range, but you are not aware of the `LARGE` and `SMALL` worksheet functions to find the second, third, fourth, ... biggest or smallest values, as explained in following URL ("https://www.excelarticles.com/excelbook/find_the_second_largest_value.html").

So you need following formulas:

```
=LARGE(B$2:B$6;1) for the largest
=LARGE(B$2:B$6;2) for the second largest
...
```

Comment: yes we need to use large functions, here  is formula which i used =INDEX($B$2:$B$12,MATCH(LARGE($A$2:$A$12,ROW(A1)),$A$2:$A$12,0),1)

Comment: hi is any one know any site where we can practice excel , with tricky question